Deep Freeze is thawed but just will not uninstall. Why?
I have Deep Freeze standard and I was able to get it to thaw (it shows red icon on polar bear).
I ran the installation file which prompted me to uninstall, which I did. After every restart, that pesky polar bear is still there and will not go away. How to manually and forcibly uninstall it? Via the command prompt better?
Anyone ever run into this before? I saw many articles but none that I could see related to having troubles uninstalling Deep Freeze in the thawed state.

Have you looked up the Deep Freeze guides for uninstallation? Which version of Deep Freeze do you have installed? What OS, version, and patch level? Please add all this and any other helpful information to the body of your question. Do not add further information down here in comments.
